# Saving data in multiple DB backends as one atomic transaction, in Django

Tags: django, django-models, redis

In a Django web app I maintain, I have a Redis powered sorted set that contains all registered usernames. Moreover, I also save said usernames in a postgresql DB (as backup).

Specifically, when a user registers, I save their username both in the DB and in Redis, like so:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(CreateAccountForm, self).save(commit=False)
    password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
    user.set_password(password)
    if commit:
        user.save() #saving in Postgresql DB
        insert_username(self.cleaned_data.get("username")) #inserting into Redis
    return user
```

The lines after `if commit:` are where the action takes place.

How do I ensure saving in DB and Redis happens **atomically**, so that in cases where it fails, I'm not left with data integrity issues? An illustrative example would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) you can do this:

```
from django.db import transaction

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(CreateAccountForm, self).save(commit=False)
    password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
    user.set_password(password)
    if commit:
        with transaction.atomic():
            user.save()  #saving in Postgresql DB
            username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
            insert_username(username)  #inserting into Redis
            # We are asserting that the username has been written to redis.
            # Otherwise, exception will be raised, not catched and transaction will be rolled back.
            assert get_username(username) == username
    return user
```

Comment: I'm certain it can roll back a postgresql transaction. What about a Redis one?

Comment: Hmmm.. How about `asserting` if the value has been written to redis and if not, raise?

Comment: Actually yes. Why don't you include that as an option in the answer as well, and I'll accept it. Covers all bases.

Comment: Very glad I could help @HassanBaig. Best regards!